# PhantomJs: Access elements drawn by js function

Tags: phantomjs

Im trying to automate scraping information from a website with login authentification using PhantomJS.
To access the login form on the page the user has to click a button, which triggers a javascript function, that draws the form.
In my code im simply calling said js function to draw the form, and try to fill the fields afterwards.
The problem is that phantomjs doesnt find the new drawn elements.
On the other side, if i take a screenshot after calling the function i can see the elements on it.
Accessing other Form elements on the page works without a problem, so i think the problem may be that phantomjs tries to access the elements before they are completely drawn.

Here's my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
url = "http://websiteURL.bla";
page.open(url, function(status) {

  if (status === "success") {
   page.evaluate(function() {
        netbar_login_signup() //js function to show login form
    });
    page.evaluate(function() {  //wait a few seconds, then fill the fields
    document.getElementById("gsnet_login_name").value = "name";
    document.getElementById("gsnet_login_passwd").value = "password";
    document.getElementById("gsnet_login_submit").click();
    },3000);
    window.setTimeout(function() { //wait a few more seconds, then take screenshot
       page.render("page.png");
     },5000);

  }
});
```

Anybody experienced similar problems or knows a solution to mine?

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got this right, but for the first wait period.

`page.evaluate` can indeed take additional arguments after the function, but those are not timeouts, those are just arguments to be passed to inside of page.evaluate. So, to wait we have to use `setTimeout` in both cases.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
url = "http://websiteURL.bla";
page.open(url, function(status) {

    // This looks a bit cleaner, less nesting
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log(status);
        phantom.exit(1); // 1 = error exit code
    }

    page.evaluate(function() {
        netbar_login_signup() //js function to show login form
    });

    // from this moment both setTimeout functions are executed simultaneously
    // the difference is that the second is waiting for 2 seconds longer

    // wait three seconds, then fill the fields
    setTimeout(function() { 
        page.evaluate(function() {  
            document.getElementById("gsnet_login_name").value = "name";
            document.getElementById("gsnet_login_passwd").value = "password";
            document.getElementById("gsnet_login_submit").click();
        });
    }, 3000);

    // wait two more seconds, then take screenshot
    setTimeout(function() { 
       page.render("page.png");
       phantom.exit(); // phantom.exit(0) // success exit code
    }, 5000);

});
```